# Java why default java version is 1.7, and not 1.8

Tags: java, linux

Recently I was installing jre on the freshly installed ubuntu (linux), and once I had to choose the version of jre to install, I chose the "default" option. This installed me jre 1.7. Why is it so? Is 1.8 unstable / incompatible / buggy to some extent?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: The latest one, 14.04 LTS

Comment: This is not exactly a Java question; it has to do with your OS' package management. In any case, since this is Ubuntu, you can install the 1.8 JDK (or JRE) by hand. Depending on the `update-alternatives` configuration, it may then come as the implementation of choice.

Comment: BTW: Ubuntu 14.04 is no longer the latest version.  14.10 was released last month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia [Ubuntu release history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases) Ubuntu 14.04 was release on 17 April 2014.

According to the Wikipedia [Java version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) Java 8 was release on 18 March 2014.

So while Java 8 could *theoretically* have made it into Ubuntu 14.04, it would have been a brave and risky decision, not least because the former's release would have happened after the latter's feature freeze date.

Canonical's decision should not be interpreted a reflection on Java 8's stability or compatibility.  Rather, it is normal practice for release engineering.

---

And in fact, there was a considerable delay before Ubuntu packages for Java 8 even made it into the main Ubuntu repositories.

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04